# SQL a left join b -> b right join a: difference in order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I sometimes read that it is equivalent to write "a left join b" and "b right jojn a". I thought I would understand this but I read in a book that this is not the case. It says that the result tuples are the same but they might be in different order. I could not find an explanation for that. I also tried to reproduce such a difference in order on my local MySQL Server, but I could not.
The only difference seems to be order of attributes.
Can anyone explain to me when or why a difference in tuple order occures?

Comment: Please quote the exact sentence from the book. Also, there is no guarantee of order if there is no `ORDER BY` clause and this applies to just about all queries.

Comment: It is a German book. It says if you change both tables in a right join and use a left join instead the returned tupels are the same but there can be a different order. I think Gerard H. Pille answered the question well.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with that. At least in MySQL, a right join is simplified to a left join ([ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html)) so `b right join a` is treated as `a left join b` behind the scenes. But yes, as long as there is no ORDER BY the server can return rows in any order.

Comment: The book being German, isn't that a warrant for its quality? ;-)  I find reading about the relational theory very refreshing for use mere programmers.  This one is a must: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6219481-sql-and-relational-theory

Comment: The book has no reference database system. So trying with MySQL could not have changed it. Thank you...
Thanks for the book... Will have a look at it. For now I will stay with my book because it is a reference book at our university course. 
Reading a book in English would certaily be good for my English skills ;)

Comment: Agreed, there are very few german programming languages.  I once came across a french programming language.  Funny thing was that the bugs were not the same as in the english version.

Comment: Relation bodies are sets of tuples, there's no order. There's no standard special relational value NULL either, but outer joins can be defined to introduce any given value for extending unmatched input tuples. SQL tables are also unordered; "result sets" (query results) are ordered if ORDER BY is used but otherwise no order is guaranteed--so "there can be a different order". SQL left & right join return columns in different order. Relationally whether columns are ordered or how a join might order them depends on the details of the algebra one is using. Please quote & reference the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes read that the order in which the tuples are returned is insignificant. The order in which a real life database returns your records, may change because the engine decides it has found a better path, using an index or not, because a block of data has been moved, ... There are big differences between the relational theory and the database of your choice. I don't mean MySQL with that.

Comment: Relation bodies are sets of tuples, there's no order.

Answer (score 5):

This is more complicated than it sounds.  First:

```
select *
from a left join b on . . . ;
```

and:

```
select *
from b right join a on . . . ;
```

Are likely to produce result sets that differ in two ways:

- The columns are in a different order.
- The rows may be in a different order.

Neither of these affects the equivalence of the result set from a set-theory perspective.  But they could have practical effects.   In general, if you care about ordering, then respectively:

- List the columns  explicitly.
- Include an `order by`.

The more important point is that `left join` and `right join` are not interchangeable when there are multiple joins, because joins always associate from left to right regardless of type.

In the following, I'm leaving out the `on` clauses.  Consider:

```
from a left join b left join c
```

You would think that the equivalent with right join is:

```
from c right join b right join a
```

But, the `join`s are grouped so the first is interpreted as:

```
from (a left join b) left join c
```

The second is:

```
from (c right join b) right join a
```

But the equivalent with `right join`s is:

```
from c right join (b right join a)
```

In both cases, every row from `a` will be int he result set.  But the results can differ depending on the overlap among the three tables.